# Global keyboard shortcut to execute text editor script

Tags: scripting, shortcut

How do I create a global keyboard shortcut that executes the script currently in the text editor?

I say global because I would like to be working in the default 3D View (no text editor displayed) and simply press a key to execute the script.  This would avoid me needing to change to the script layout, run the script, return to 3d View every time.

<kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>P</kbd> only seems to work when the text editor is focused.

In User preferences->Input, I tried adding a new "Run Script" event ('text.run_script') to the Window (Global) section and assigned it a key, but the console reports 'event has invalid window'.

Comment: i think it's possible to set global keyboard shortcuts, and also write an operator that can run a script, but the problem could be that if you have multiple text blocks, how is it going to choose which to execute if no text editors are open? -- unless the operator always looks for Textblocks with a certain name or prefix

Comment: you wouldn't need to set up a global shortcut for this, an operator bound to a shortcut for 3d view might make more sense.

Comment: there is an addon called **script runner** you load multiple files and run the one you want

Comment: I wasn't aware of script runner addon, but it totally makes sense if that exists already!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you are only going to re-executing this script when 3D View is open you might add the shortcut to 3D View (global). I propose a different shortcut as <kbd>alt</kbd>+<kbd>p</kbd> is for showing the 'clear parent' menu, but it's up to you.

[image]

At the end of this list..

[image]

**generic_executor.py**

```
# something to test with..
import bpy
import random

x = random.randint(-6, 6)
y = random.randint(-6, 6)
z = random.randint(-6, 6)

bpy.ops.mesh.primitive_cube_add(radius=1, location=(x, y, z))
```

**operator.py**

```
import bpy


class GlobalScriptRunner(bpy.types.Operator):
    """Tooltip"""
    bl_idname = "view3d.global_script_runner"
    bl_label = "Global Script Runner"

    #@classmethod
    #def poll(cls, context):
    #    return context.active_object is not None

    def execute(self, context):
        print('i get called')
        textblock_name = 'generic_executor.py'
        textblock_as_string = bpy.data.texts[textblock_name].as_string()
        exec(textblock_as_string)
        return {'FINISHED'}


def register():
    bpy.utils.register_class(GlobalScriptRunner)


def unregister():
    bpy.utils.unregister_class(GlobalScriptRunner)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    register()
```

To wrap this into a reusable add-on requires more time than I have, but it's not the purpose of this answer. The benefit of having this as an addon would be that you could create a panel for 3dview in which you can type or select a textblock to be executed when the shortcut is triggered, rather than this hard coded suggestion, where it only executes a textblock named `generic_executor.py`

---

edit:

Here's something you could use as a starting point, it creates a panel in 3dview (right side panel) and allows you to pick a textblock. Whenever you trigger the operator `view3d.global_script_runner` , it would look at the name of the selected file and execute it.

https://gist.github.com/zeffii/2b488961226ee1ecefcf

Comment: I have the time can I try to write this ?

Comment: @zeffii Thanks for such a comprehensive answer.  I haven't had a chance to try it out yet.  I'll let you know how I get on.

Comment: this eliminates the need for overriding the context !

Comment: yeah, but exec might be slower on complex scripts ( i vaguely recall reading about this..but can't pinpoint where) --  unless that's exactly what's called behind the run operator... :)

Comment: Related: http://blender.stackexchange.com/a/47678/2843

Comment: This looks great and all, but how do you set this up? Simply entering view3d.global_script_runner into the keyboard shortcuts pane doesn't really work.

Comment: Nvm, sort of got it. You have to paste the operator.py file in the blender Text Editor pane.